# Android Emulator Displaying Weird When Scaled to Real Size

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, emulation

I'm currently using Eclipse Helios installed on Ubuntu 10.10 running Java version 1.6.0_20 (OpenJDK Runtime Environment IcedTea6 1.9.8)..... Now that this lengthy introduction in done, here's my problem:

When I launch an AVD on my machine and I choose the option to 'scale display to real size' my emulator displays all weird. (see image). However when I choose NOT to scale the display to real size it works perfectly fine...

[image: pretty ugly isn't it]

Thing is I need to edit the display size otherwise the emulator spans over the boundaries of my laptop screen...

Any help?

--------------------------- Edit ---------------------------

Call me stupid, but how do I use the patch for this bug that can be found here: review.source.android.com/#/c/24433

Comment: This question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621684/problem-with-android-emulator-scale-option-lossy-picture

Comment: Maybe a workaround until you find the problem: Try to use the fullscreen mode by pressing Alt+Return.

Comment: Call me stupid, but how do I use the patch for this that can be found here: https://review.source.android.com/#/c/24433/ ?

Answer (score 0):

When you scale the display to real size, you have two options - you can set the screen size in (virtual) inches, as well as the dpi for the monitor.  Are either of these set?  What is the scale ratio given.  It's easy for the display to come out strange if you have an unusual dpi setting for a certain screen size.  Decide how many inches you want, then play with the dpi settings.  You can hit the question mark next to monitor DPI to give you an idea of what would be a good value to set.