# How do I use this Android Emulator Bug Patch?

Tags: android, linux, patch

2 Days ago I posted a question regarding my emulator displaying weird when changing screen sizes (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040219/android-emulator-displaying-weird-when-scaled-to-real-size).

I eventually found what seems to be a patch for this particular bug over [here](https://review.source.android.com/#/c/24433/). But, and I do feel stupid asking this, how do I use this patch??

I've never used a patch and this doesn't seem like a simple exe that I run...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `patch` program to apply it to your source code.

Usually, you can run `patch -p0 < the-patch-file`. But you may have to adjust the p value parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed process of building android tools from sources described on the android [source](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) site. The adt plugin stored in development/tools/eclipse.